# ARCore Extensions for AR Foundation (Unity) — Error Upon Build

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

I am attempting to build an app that uses ARCore's Cloud Anchors for AR Foundation. When I add the ARCore Extensions object to the scene and build, I receive the following error. Help/insight is much appreciated. (I am building for Android.)

```
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue].FindEntry (TKey key) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue].ContainsKey (TKey key) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
Google.XR.ARCoreExtensions.Editor.Internal.AndroidDependenciesHelper.GetAllSessionConfigs () (at Packages/arcore-extensions-package/Editor/Scripts/Internal/AndroidDependenciesHelper.cs:65)
Google.XR.ARCoreExtensions.Editor.Internal.CompatibilityCheckPreprocessBuild.OnPreprocessBuild (UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at Packages/arcore-extensions-package/Editor/Scripts/Internal/ModulesWorkflow/CompatibilityCheckPreprocessBuild.cs:66)
UnityEditor.Build.BuildPipelineInterfaces+<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<OnBuildPreProcess>b__1 (UnityEditor.Build.IPreprocessBuildWithReport bpp) (at <0b8db76a688c4d18a15dd7dfe092a035>:0)
UnityEditor.Build.BuildPipelineInterfaces.InvokeCallbackInterfacesPair[T1,T2] (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] oneInterfaces, System.Action`1[T] invocationOne, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] twoInterfaces, System.Action`1[T] invocationTwo, System.Boolean exitOnFailure) (at <0b8db76a688c4d18a15dd7dfe092a035>:0)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I solved this one pretty quickly.

The ARCoreExtensions object has 4 required fields [listed here](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity-arf#add_ar_foundation_objects_to_your_scene). I had gotten them all to work except for ARCore Extensions Config, because the object did not exist in the Assets nor Scene dropdown. Then I found [these instructions](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity-arf/session-config#configure_extension_features_in_arcoreextensionsconfig) which then allowed me to fulfil the necessary fields for ARCoreExtensions, and build the project successfully.

(Note:)
I had placed the entire ARCore Extensions package into the Packages folder of the Unity project, which lead to some other problems later on (As opposed to the proper `Window>Package Manager>+ (dropdown)>Add package from disk>package.json`). So, if my explanation above is not the actual problem, then the package importing must be.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to re-import the sample project and re-connect the configuration object located in cloundanchorexample/configurations to the configurations slot on the ARCoreExtensions object in my scene.

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!